# Javascript window.location.href comparison with index.php or root name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run a specific piece of code in JS when

1)The page is mysite.com/index.php or
2) when index is not present e.g mysite.com . (You can do that using apache )

For 1 I am using 
1)`if ( /index\.php$/.test(window.location.href)) { //code here }`

How can I do it for both ?

2)I have tried

```
if ( /http:\/\/mysite\.com/g.test(window.location.href))
{
}
```

But this works for every url (e.g mysite.com/anythinghere.php)

Comment: `.test()` compares a regular expression against a string so you'll need to escape the forward slashes. You could just use `==` to compare the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if you want know you loaded the home page

```
 if(/\/(index\.php)?$/.test(window.location.pathname)){
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this more easily by comparing `window.location.pathname` value.

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/' || window.location.pathname == '/index.php') {
    // code here
}
```